# FOR statement to parse datetime stamp in file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

How will I accomplish the following in a FOR statement?

I have files in a windows PC directory that I want to identify by all or part of a datetime stamp that is part of the files name, ie-

```
CLIENT CODE / ID            DATETIME STAMP 
0000090000010009.CLIENTNAME.20121212140022.txt
0001090000010009.CLIENTNAME.20130916110025.txt
0001090000010009.CLIENTNAME.20130908150022.txt
```

I do not have to open/read the file. I just need to identify files in a particular date time range to either MOVE, DELETE or COPY them.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "*.clientname.*.*"') do (
    set "dts=%%c"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "yyyy=!dts:~0,4!"
    set "mm=!dts:~4,2!"
    set "dd=!dts:~6,2!"
    set "hh=!dts:~8,2!"
    set "min=!dts:~10,2!"
    set "sec=!dts:~12,2!"
    echo File: %%a.%%b.%%c.%%d date/time: !dd!/!mm!/!yyyy! -- !hh!:!min!:!sec!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: I get the following message: "in was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @E.Clay    sorry, ugly bug: forgot the for loop variable declaration `%%a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` command with wildcard. So say you want the file `0000090000010009.CLIENTNAME.20121212140022.txt` you can do:

`dir *20121212140022*`

If you want to put it in a loop then `for /F` will do the trick:

`for /F %x in ('dir *20121212140022* /b /a-d ') do del %x`

Comment: This appears to work, except that when I use in a batch file, I get the ") unexpected at this time". What am I doing wrong?.      for /F %%x in ('dir %1 /b /a-d ') do echo %%x

Comment: Thanks I am good to go now, thanks.